# Image dimensions on hover in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

At this moment, to see image dimensions I have to open Properties of an image with right click. It's rather irritating if I have to quickly check sizes of dozens of images on the same page.

Is there any way I can make it show me the image size when I hover it? A simple balloon or similar info is enough. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) extension.

After installation, restart Firefox and then activate the **Display Image Dimensions** function from the menu:

[image]

You will now see the dimension of images displayed right next to them:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I know that. This is how I did so far, but thought there is a hover way to do it. Can't believe such addon does not exist yet.

Comment: @JoeM: I'm sorry, it's the best I could find :( In Chrome you could have this through the Developer Tools: http://i.imgur.com/k1q5Dsp.png ...in case that helps any.